# Error on my syntax, please advise on the appropriate syntax for JavaScript & JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rendering

I'm very new to JavaScript as well as jQuery, on my visual studio code its saying expression expected near `var se` and also it says `'}'` expected near `{"URL":window.location.href,}` what will be the appropriate fix for this.

Please advise.

Here's my code:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
        function renderSurvey(URL){
        var se = new SurveyEmbed("FM9wg_ghhgvjh","https://formsss.tester.com/","https://jhbjh.kjbkjedge.net/mfpembedconkhtweu/");
        var context = {"URL":window.location.href,};se.renderButton( context);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Remove that trailing comma after the .href

Comment: In regards to the trailing comma not being invalid, the user may be seeing VSCode provide jslist feedback, which may have warnings around trailing commas.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing actually wrong with your code, my Visual Studio Code also doesn't give any errors.

You can improve on readability though, I think something like this is way cleaner (other people might disagree):

```
function renderSurvey(URL) {
  let se = new SurveyEmbed(
    "FM9wg_ghhgvjh",
    "https://formsss.tester.com/",
    "https://jhbjh.kjbkjedge.net/mfpembedconkhtweu/"
  );
  let context = { URL: window.location.href };

  se.renderButton(context);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your syntax, Visual Studio Code is wrong (the trailing comma noted by Taplar [is allowed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Trailing_commas)). Try running your code in a web browser -- does it work as expected? If not then open up your browser's debug console and tell us the error that you see.

Comment: I get the follwoing Uncaught ReferenceError: html is not defined

Comment: That is telling us that there is a javascript variable called "html" that is being used but is not defined. Your provided code doesn't include an "html" variable, so this error is coming from somewhere else. The console should tell you what file and line the error is coming from.